# Is there any simple primality test for large integer for students in the high school level?

Tags: number-theory, primality-test

In high school the standard primality test of an integer $n$ is to find a square root of this integer then test divisibility of $n$ with primes less than the integer part of $\sqrt{n}$ but this method is difficult to do by hand for large number then , **Is there any simple primality test for large integer for students in the high school  level for example  $12109$**?

Comment: I think in all case it needs to work.

Comment: $\sqrt {12109}\approx 110$...not really all that hard to do by hand.  Otherwise, [Miller Rabin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) is probably the simplest.

Comment: Also the [Pocklington primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test) is nice. The example is done with $27457$.

Comment: Another fairly easy test is [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) ... it's a mechanical work.

Comment: I don't think that students are expected to check such numbers by hand. Correct me, if I am wrong. A little better than trial division is the method also considering quadratic residues, for example, the given number can easily be detected to be the sum of two squares. It was such a method that was used to factor $2^{67}-1$ by hand, but it took the Sundays of three years (i right now do not remember who did this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Write $n-1 = 2^sd$ where $d$ is odd and $s$ is non-negative:
>
> - $n$ is a strong probable-prime base $a$ (an $a$-SPRP) if either $a^d \equiv 1 \pmod n$ or $(a^d)^{2r} \equiv -1 \pmod n$ for some non-negative $r$ less than $s$.

For large integers for a human but small for number theory, this website lists limits values for the first primes sprp tests.

https://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove2_3.html

e.g. for $n<1\,373\,653$ then $\{2,3\}$-SPRP is sufficient.

This paper http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1326/020-Forisek.pdf

suggests that for integers $n<2^{32}$ we can improve the $\{2,3,5,7,11\}$-SPRP test from the former website by performing a $\{2,7,61\}-SPRP$ test instead.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2481258/589 for 64-bit integers

Comment: First one is also known as [Miller-Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test)