# About $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{1 \leq i \leq n}\left( 1-\frac{1}{p_i} \right)$ where $p_i$ is the ith prime

Tags: limits, number-theory, optimization, prime-numbers, algorithms

I am doing some tutorials on programming, and I am on the classic "write a program that returns true if and only if the input is a prime number". The solution is straightforward: for every number $d$ between $2$ and $N-1$ test if $d$ is a divisor of $N$.

The first optimization is to reduce the testing interval to $[2, \sqrt{N}]$.

The next optimization is to reduce the testing interval by eliminating the even numbers in it (plus a particular test for 2).

Now becomes the next optimizations: *what if I eliminate the multiples of 3 too?* With the due adjustings, it reduces the interval to 1/3 of its original size. (It is just Inclusion-Exclusion from Combinatorics.)

We can do this further for the next primes. Summing up, after $k$ interactions the set is reduced to $\prod_{1 \leq i \leq k}\left( 1-\frac{1}{p_i} \right)$ of its original size.

Therefore, my question is:

What is the  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \prod_{1 \leq i \leq n}\left( 1-\frac{1}{p_i} \right)$?

Probably the limit has no known "closed form", but it would be cool to know it to at least some decimal places. After all, it can be useful to establish a point when the optimization efforts supersede the gains.

Comment: Thanks, I have edited it.

Comment: Mertens' third theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems

Comment: The limit you're looking for is equal to zero.

Comment: If you're interested in a faster primality test for medium-sized numbers that's relatively easy to code, take a look at the deterministic variants of the Miller-Rabin test. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2481148/207316 & http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/

Comment: Many thanks, I will read about it later!